# java: Is it possible to set a lambda expression for an array of Buttons is a for loop? If so how?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //if any button in the array is pressed, disable it.
    button[i].setOnAction( ae -> { button[i].setDisable(true) } );
}
```

However, I get a error saying `"local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final"`.  How might I still do something like the code above (if it is even possible)? If it can't be done, what should be done instead to get a similar result?

Comment: You should be able to get the button from the `ActionEvent` instead of another array lookup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message says, local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final ("effectively final" meaning the compiler can make it final for you).

Simple workaround:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    final int ii = i;
    button[i].setOnAction( ae -> { button[ii].setDisable(true) } );
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you.  I come from a C++ programming background, things like this in Java throw me off sometimes...just like when comparing Strings.  Thank you for a quick and accurate answer.

Comment: You could also make a reference to `button[i]` and reuse that. `Button current = button[i]` and `current.setDisable(true);` within the lambda.

Comment: If you're curious why: variable values are passed *by value* into the lambda, and I guess they wanted to leave the possibility of passing non-final variables by reference in a later version. It also avoids the confusion that `() -> {i = 5;}` wouldn't actually change `i` (if that lambda was allowed without `i` being final).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using lambdas, you can benefit also from other features of Java 8, like streams.

For instance, `IntStream`:

> A sequence of primitive int-valued elements supporting sequential and parallel aggregate operations. This is the int primitive specialization of Stream.

can be used to replace the for loop:

```
IntStream.range(0,10).forEach(i->{...});
```

so now you have an index that can be used to your purpose:

```
IntStream.range(0,10)
         .forEach(i->button[i].setOnAction(ea->button[i].setDisable(true)));
```

Also you can generate a stream from an array:

```
 Stream.of(button).forEach(btn->{...});
```

In this case you won't have an index, so as @shmosel suggests, you can use the source of the event:

```
Stream.of(button)
          .forEach(btn->btn.setOnAction(ea->((Button)ea.getSource()).setDisable(true)));
```

*EDIT*

As @James_D suggests, there's no need of downcasting here:

```
Stream.of(button)
      .forEach(btn->btn.setOnAction(ea->btn.setDisable(true)));
```

In both cases, you can also benefit from parallel operations:

```
IntStream.range(0,10).parallel()
         .forEach(i->button[i].setOnAction(ea->button[i].setDisable(true)));

Stream.of(button).parallel()
          .forEach(btn->btn.setOnAction(ea->btn.setDisable(true)));
```

Comment: The `Stream.of(button).forEach(...)` example doesn't need to get the source of the action event in the event handler. The variable `btn` is in scope there (so you can avoid the ugly downcast).

Comment: Parallel operations on JavaFx nodes? I thought all operations need to be on the fx thread

Comment: @Adam from the node [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html): "Node objects may be constructed and modified on any thread as long they are not yet attached to a Scene. An application must attach nodes to a Scene, and modify nodes that are already attached to a Scene, on the JavaFX Application Thread."  For just 10 buttons, though, [streaming the setOnAction in parallel is of questionable value](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/StreamParallelGuidance.html).

Comment: @jewelsea Correct me if I'm wrong, but in this case we are just adding an event handler to a collection of nodes, and this doesn't affect their rendering. It could be done even with the nodes attached to the scene. This has nothing to do with the action of disabling the node on being clicked, that will be executed on the JavaFX Application thread. For sure, operations related to rendering will fail if the nodes are already attached to the scene.

Comment: Jose, parallel code for such operations is probably going to work fine, but, in most cases, I wouldn't recommend it.  There remains a slight (though unlikely) risk that it could have concurrent side effects (for example onAction is a property that somebody could set a listener on which accesses the scene graph).   Also, parallelizing a setter will perform slower than sequential code unless you are setting ~10000 action listeners.  Might be a good topic for another stack overflow question or to ask the [openjfx-dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Event` to get the source `Node`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < button.length; i++)
{
     button[i].setOnAction(event ->{
         ((Button)event.getSource()).setDisable(true);
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambda expressions are effectively like an annonymous method which works on stream. In order to avoid any unsafe operations, Java has made that no external variables which can be modified, can be accessed in a lambda expression.

In order to work around it,

final int index=button[i];
And use index instead of **i** inside your lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

You say If the button is pressed, but in your example all the buttons in the list will be disabled. Try to associate a listener to each button rather than just disable it.

For the logic, do you mean something like that :

```
Arrays.asList(buttons).forEach(
        button -> button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                button.setEnabled(false);

            }
}));
```

I Also like Sedrick's answer but you have to add an action listener inside the loop .